# find folder named "downloads" in the current directory

Tags: bash

I intend to get a path which is named "downlads " under 'volumns' in the current directory

```
$ cd /volumes/**/downloads; pwd; cd -
/volumes/Transcend/downloads
/Users/me/downloads
```

change to them, print and change back,

Is there a handy way to handle this?

Comment: So you want to list the contents of all directories named "downloads" recursively?

Comment: Can you repair all of the typos in the post, and then explain why you need to cd to them only to immediately return? Why not just print them?

Comment: I got it, apply `echo`, thank you for the reminder @JeffSchaller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do this using `find` command as:

```
find ./ -iname '*downloads*'
```

`-iname`: search for case-insensitive.

Is there any specific reason to change to the searched directory and then printing `pwd` and then changing back again?

BTW, you'd need to run this command from the directory in which you want to search for `downloads`

Comment: This will match files as well as folders. You might want to add `-type d` to only find folders, and/or use `-name` instead of `-iname` to match the capitalisation exactly (i.e. exclude "Downloads").